# Как связать две таблицы внутри контроллера?

Tags: php, laravel

Внутри релятивной бд имеются две соответствующие таблицы

```
- Названия категорий
- Списки категорий
```

Вывод осуществляется посредством "БЫДЛО кода"

```
$cat_name = DB::table('cat_name')->get();
foreach($cat_name as $row) {
    $child = DB::table('categories')->where('id','=',$row->id)->get();
    echo $row->title;
    foreach($child as $c) {
        echo $c->title;
    }
}
```

Можно ли как то в пределах одного лишь контроллера решить проблему релятивности?

Comment: Чем обусловлена просьба решить проблему в пределах контроллера? Почему бы не сформулировать обычный запрос с JOIN-ами? Потом уже переведёте его на Eloquent. Думаю, вашу задачу можно решить одним запросом на выборку.

Comment: Можете продемонстрировать пример? Благодарю.

Comment: Пример на основе чего? Вы не указали структуру ваших таблиц.

Comment: К примеру вот как перевести вот этот запрос в Eloquent "SELECT * FROM categories JOIN categories_parent ON categories.parent_id = categories.id"?

Comment: `DB::table('categories')->leftJoin('categories_parent', 'categories.parent_id', '=', 'categories.id')`

Comment: А как потом в цикле вывести данные из таблиц если там поле к примеру 'id' повторяется?

Comment: Обновите вопрос. Скажите, что сделали так-то. Получили массив такой-то. Что делать дальше? Я отвечу на этот вопрос.